# What is the result of the add function in manytomany?

Tags: django, many-to-many

this is my model

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='myuser')
```

when i write following code

```
MyUser.items.add(item1)
```

i want to know if it was added or duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the `myuser.items` will be a `set`, which means it won't create any duplicate entries even we are forcing to do so

**Example:**

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [2]: item = Item.objects.create(field_name="some_value")

In [3]: usr = User.objects.get(id=1)

In [4]: myuser = MyUser.objects.create(user=usr)

In [5]: myuser.items.count()
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: myuser.items.add(item)

In [7]: myuser.save()

In [8]: myuser.items.count()
Out[8]: 1

In [9]: myuser.items.add(item)

In [10]: myuser.save()

In [11]: myuser.items.count()
Out[11]: 1
```

Here you can see, the `count` is not increasing while we adding the same `item` instance again and again

Comment: is this best way..??

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I just think it is inefficient and not clean...As a result of the return, i thought i would know

Comment: from [django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) they are taught us the same way to do so

Answer (score 1):

.add() does not create duplicates, it adds the item if it is not present in the `user_items` junction table.

However, you need to call .save() first

Just like when calling `my_model.attribute = 'value'`

you need to call `.save()` for the actual value to be saved.